# How find this $\max{|A|}$ if $A=\{S_{i}|S_{i}\equiv 1\pmod 2\}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

> let $(a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{2014})$ be a permutation of  $(1,2,3,\cdots,2014)$,and define
>   $$S_{k}=a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{k},k=1,2,3,\cdots,2014$$
>   Find the  $\max{|A|}$,

where $A=\{S_{i}|S_{i}\equiv 1\pmod 2\}$
and $|A|=card(A)$

First this problem is Shanghai mathematics olympiad question in 2014 .because this problem is  the front of the test paper,In general,this problem maybe it's easy.

[image]
my idea:
if $S_{i},i=1,2,\cdots,2014$ is odd,then is in sets $A$,so we only find this odd numbers maximum.But I can't.Thank you

Comment: Is the problem to find a permutation such that $|A|$ is maximized?

Comment: Hello,No,Find the $S_{i}$ is odd numbers maximum

Comment: $\max A$ is simply $S_{2014}$, which is very simple. But you stated the problem as looking for $\max|A|$...

Comment: $|A|$ in  set mean card(A) in china book

Comment: can you tell us what the solution would be if it were $N=6$ instead of $N=2014$? Maybe from the solution we can figure out what the question would have to be ...

Comment: maybe this  permutation $(5,4,2,6,3,1)$  and so on, is maximum,because Now $S_{1}=5,S_{2}=9,S_{3}=11,S_{4}=17,S_{5}=20,S_{6}=21$,then numbers is $5$

Comment: Yes, alright, so I in fact understood you correctly. Note that the number $5$ is also retrieved by the permutation $(1,2,4,6,3,5)$, as I had given in my answer below. So, $1511$ appears still plausible to me as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would say $\frac{2014(2014+1)}{2}$, because this is the value of $S_{2014}$ (when you sum up everything, no matter the permutation, you get $\sum_{i=1}^{2014}i$ ) and it's odd cause when you sum up the n-th first integers, modulo 2, it's like $1 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 0 + \ldots$.

So with respect to $N$, you get congruence mod 2 : $1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,\ldots$. In other words, the sum is even iff $N \equiv 1$ or $2 \mod{4}$, which is the case with 2014. (you can also just ask your calculator $\frac{2014(2014+1)}{2}$ if you don't believe me)

Comment: Oh,|A|=card(A).But Thank you

Comment: Oh so your question is to find $|A|$ ? But then the max is confusing... Are they several sets $A$ ? Could you precise your question please ?

Comment: Now I have Upload the this problem

Answer (score 0):

I also don't know what exactly is being asked but I think if the permutation is such that

$S_1=1$, $S_2=1+2$, $S_3=1+2+4$, $S_4=1+2+4+6$, etc. then you already have $2014/2+1=1008$ odd  $S_i$'s. Then $S_{1010}=S_{1008}+3+5$ is odd again, so is $S_{1012}=S_{1008}+3+5+7+9$, etc. So you would have $1008+(2014-1008)/2=1511$ odd $S_i$'s. I think this is the maximum possible cardinality of $A$, but in any case, the maximum possible cardinality of $A$ would then be $\ge 1511$.